# Custom verbatim commands writing into index

Tags: indexing, fancyvrb

I have created a custom fancyvrb command via `\CustomVerbatimCommand{\afun}{Verb}{}` to use for writing programming language functions, say `\afun|object.method.blah|`, etc.

I would like to automatically build an index of all mentions of function names.

I know I could try to do that with ordinary LaTeX commands, e.g. with something like:

```
\newcommand{\afun}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
```

That will create an index entry with a function name.

Is there any way to achieve that, but with custom verbatim commands of fancyvrb?

Comment: Could you please be more specific with some typical examples? Do you really need verbatim mode?

Comment: @egreg, I'll put an example shortly. I think I need verbatim because of underscores in function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex

\NewDocumentCommand\afun{v}{%
  \texttt{#1}\index{#1@\ifun{#1}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifun}{v}{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\afun{object.method.blah}

\afun{object.method_2.blah}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

If you only need the underscore, among the special characters, this seems the cleanest approach.

[image]

Comment: Looks good. I guess you meant package `makeidx`. However, when I tried to compile your example, I'm getting `(xparse) Unknown argument type 'v' replaced by 'm'. Fingers crossed ...` Any clues?

Comment: @Michal You have an outdated distribution. Upgrade it. For `imakeidx` I suggest you to look at its documentation. `;-)`

Comment: indeed... even though it is texlive up to date with Ubuntu repositories. I will get back here as soon as I update. Thanks so far anyway! Your solution looks very promising.

Comment: I finally was able to update my texlive. Your solution works perfectly so far. Thanks!